# How to pass value of variable in procedure to Javascript function in Apex

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, oracle-apex

I have variable in local procedure that rendering data to pop-up window
I'm using oracle apex 20.2
Oracle Database 18 c

Variable name :l_factor_count
[image: as shown in image here]

I want to pass this variable value to be used in Javascript function inside this procedure
[image: If I put static value it's works fine but if I use the procedure variable it won't work!]

After I did some research I found that this variable is local and needs to be related with page item but I don't know how do that because I use the procedure to do all the work and rendering data in pop-up as I said before.

Comment: Is the code in the two images part of the same procedure? Or is it part of the same package but different procedures?

Comment: yes both in the same procedure.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways of doing what you want

**Divide you code in 2 parts.**

1º Execute the PL/SQL required sending the values e returning them accordingly. Submitting this values in a dynamic action is APEX 101, so you should be fine here.

2º Execute a second action with the JavaScript code grabbing these values.

**Execute an Ajax Call**

Use [apex.server.process](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2/aexjs/apex.server.html#.process) to call you PL/SQL function and make it return your values to continue the process.

---

I do not advise you to my JavaScript and PL and if possible try to avoid it.

If you don't know how to do the steps from either item, then you might be doing stuff that, at the moment, is to advanced for you. So please check out some tutorials, anything online is going to help a lot.